# Why are my orchid’s leaves turning brown?

Tags: houseplants, leaves, orchids

I’m a new orchid owner, I don’t know much about them, but my orchid’s leaves are starting to turn brown!!! I keep it away from the windows so they don’t receive too much sunlight but I believe it gets the right amount of sunlight from the sliding door. We keep the blinds open during the day. I live in South Florida so the sun here can easily burn plants that aren’t supposed to receive direct sunlight. I touched the leaves and they don’t feel hot and the flowers look healthy. I’m not sure what the problem is, please help!!

Comment: Welcome, Elisa! Could you [edit] your post and include a few pictures, please? The [tour] and the [help] will explain more about how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

how often do you water your orchid? and do you use fertilizer?

Depending on temperature/humidity/and size of your plant you can water your orchid once every 2-3 weeks (water once a week if your pot is small or you feel the medium is dry out. I water mine once every 3 week but I live in temperature max ~86F).

Place the orchid under running water until drainage hole has water coming out. Drain the remaining water until it is no longer running out of the drainage hole. When watering ensure you do not get the leaves of the orchid wet. Orchid do not like to get their leaves wet.

For fertilizer use a orchid specific fertilize. Do not over fertilize as this will burn the plant. I only fertilize when a flower stem is growing (fertilize when you water)